# Missing services when filtering aws cost mangement by user defined tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-iot, cost-management

I have a couple of AWS services tagged with custom tag, after enabling user defined tags in AWS cost management it seems `IoT rules`, `ECS` not showing in my cost graph.
I verified that those services are correctly tagged with the right tag and I have been waiting more than 24 hours.
Any idea what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm, have you activated the tags you've assigned to resources? Here are the instructions for how to do this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/activating-tags.html